# C++ signal listener for non-child pid

Tags: c++, design-patterns, signals

I'm using C++ and I need the equivalent of SIGCHLD for a process I'm aware of (i.e. I know it's pid), but did not spawn.

Is there a well established design pattern to listen/watch/monitor another process's lifespan when it is not your child or in your group or session?

EDIT: I am specifically trying to be aware of abnormal terminations (i.e. seg faults, signals, etc...). I would like to eavesdrop on signals the process in question receives.

Comment: Are you targeting a particular operating system?

Comment: I would prefer not to tie myself to an operating system, but if I had to it would be Linux-ish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it follows a specific pattern, *per se*, but one technique is to have the process establish a connection to the watcher. The watcher monitors the connection, and when it becomes closed, it knows the process has shutdown.

If the watcher wants to know if the watched process is responsive or not, you can use the connection to monitor heartbeat messages that the process is obliged to provide.

If the watcher wants to know whether the watched process is making progress, the heartbeat message could provide state information that would allow the watcher to monitor that.

Different operating systems may provide different ways to achieve the same objective. For example, on Linux, the watcher could use `inotify` to monitor the `/proc` entry for that process to determine if the process is up or down. The BSD `kqueue` has a similar capability. The process could export its heartbeat/state into shared memory, and the watcher could use a timed wait on a semaphore to see if the data is being updated.

If the process is a third-party program, and source is not available, then you would have to resort to some method similar to `inotify`/`kqueue`, or as a last resort, poll the kernel state (similar to the way the `top` utility works).

Comment: I need a method that is robust enough to handle abnormal termination. Seg faults, kill signals, etc...

Comment: The heartbeat sounds promising, but I don't want to lose bunch of CPU cycles checking. I would prefer to listen to signals the process in question receives.

Comment: @Zak: If knowing why the process died is a requirement, it would be easier to wrap the executable around a dummy parent whose only purpose is to capture the `wait` status of the child when it dies.

Comment: @Zak: The monitor process would use `select` on connections to passively collect heartbeat messages.

Comment: The dummy parent is certainly a direction I'm looking at, but I'm trying to solve this problem with a bit more "finesse". I'm working in a tightly integrated environment, and making a dummy parent may send big ripples through my pond. It would definitely work though.

Comment: I have never used select/poll/epoll but I just finished some preliminary reading, and it says they are all for multiplexing files? Can you explain how I would use these functions to monitor the life of a program?

Comment: Multiplexing file descriptors. When the process connects to the watcher process, the watcher will have a socket connected to the watched process. The watcher would have a separate socket for each process that connects to it. You need to find resources that explain basic client server socket programming. Explaining that to you is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation, would you be able to provide a link to any resources you enjoy over the topic socket programming that would be useful in this particular instance.

Comment: @Zak: [UNIX Network Programming, by W. Richard Stevens, et al.](http://www.amazon.com/Unix-Network-Programming-Volume-Networking/dp/0131411551/), [UNIX Socket FAQ](http://developerweb.net/viewforum.php?id=70), [libevent](http://libevent.org/), and [boost.asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost_asio.html).